# ScrollViewContainer wont scroll when I use views to sequence from instead of surfaces using Famous

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I am sequencing a `ScrollViewContainer` with some views I created. The views each have a surface but when I do this the `ScrollViewContainer` wont scroll anymore. When I use a list of surfaces to `sequenceFrom([Surface, Surface, Surface])` the ScrollViewContainer works fine but when I use a list of Views `sequenceFrom([MyView, MyView, MyView])` it wont scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your `View` will need a renderable that will pipe to the `View` like a Surface.

In this case you would pipe the `Surface` events to the `View` output event handler from within your `View`.

**[See line 62 of this example on jsBin.](http://jsbin.com/hesuca/2/edit?js,output#J:L62)**

```js
surface.pipe(view._eventOutput);
```

Comment: since i was in the view I used "this" i.e. surface.pipe(this._eventOutput);

Comment: Yes, you are right to pipe it to the scope of your view.